# Relation of dimension about subspaces in surjective linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $U$ and $V$ be vector spaces over a scalar field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $T : U \to V$ be a surjective linear transformation and let $W$ be a vector subspace of $V$.

Define the preimage: 
$T^{−1}(W) := \{u \in U \mid T(u) \in W\}$.

Prove:

$\dim U+\dim W=\dim V+\dim T^{-1}(W)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dim U = \mathrm{rank}\ T+\mathrm{nullity}\ T = \dim V+\mathrm{nullity}\ T$, by the rank nullity theorem and surjectivity of $T$.

Now consider $T|_{T^{-1}(W)}:T^{-1}(W) \rightarrow W$. This is again surjective, and together with the rank nullity theorem, we have
$\dim T^{-1}(W) = \mathrm{rank}\ T|_{T^{-1}(W)}+\mathrm{nullity}\ T|_{T^{-1}(W)} = \dim W+\mathrm{nullity}\ T|_{T^{-1}(W)}$.

Combining these, we get $\dim U + \dim W = \dim V + \dim T^{-1}(W) + \mathrm{nullity}\ T - \mathrm{nullity}\ T|_{T^{-1}(W)}$

However, we know that $\mathrm{nullity}\ T = \mathrm{nullity}\ T|_{T^{-1}(W)}$, because $0 \in W$. Hence the result, $\dim U + \dim W = \dim V + \dim T^{-1}(W)$, follows.